# Is it possible to configure PayPal to receive Notifications in Text instead of HTML email

Tags: paypal

I was wondering if it is at all possible to configure PayPal Admin notification to receive in Text instead of html email. I would like to have email body that contains the order details.

Answer (score 0):

You can change from HTML to text in your PayPal account's settings -> [Notifications](https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/mysettings/notifications), first option.

Comment: 0



Thank Preston. It worked. PayPal account's settings -> Notifications changed Email type to Text.

Comment: You should use webhooks or at worst the old IPN service, reading emails programmatically makes no sense whatsoever as a solution to anything

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. It worked. PayPal account's settings -> Notifications changed Email type to Text.

Now the text in the body I can reads using C#.